# Neo4j Cypher: How to iterate over ExecutionResult result

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In this code, how could I iterate over all the nodes in the ExecutionResult result?

```
CypherParser parser = new CypherParser();
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( graphDb );
Query query = parser.parse( "START n=node(2) MATCH (n)<-[:IS_A]-(x) RETURN x" );
ExecutionResult result = engine.execute( query );
// iterate over nodes in result and print all properties
```

Answer (score 9):

The javadoc for Cypher isn't very clear about this, possibly because there isn't any.

So I re-created your code in a "trial" that demonstrates how to iterate over the properties of nodes in the match. The domain is kinds of fruit, where each kind is linked to the "fruit" node. The relevant snippet is this, after running the query:

```
    Iterator<Node> kindsOfFruit = result.columnAs("x");
    while (kindsOfFruit.hasNext()) {
        Node kindOfFruit = kindsOfFruit.next();
        System.out.println("Kind #" + kindOfFruit.getId());
        for (String propertyKey : kindOfFruit.getPropertyKeys()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + propertyKey + " : " +
               kindOfFruit.getProperty(propertyKey));
        }
    }
```

It's the `result.columnAs("x")` that is the key. The cleverly named `String n` parameter refers to a "column name" in the result clause. In this example we want the "x" column and we expect it to contain `Node` objects, so we can assign straight to an `Iterator<Node>` and then use that.

If the  column can't be found, we'll get an `org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException`.

If we ask for assignment to the wrong class, we'll get the usual `java.lang.ClassCastException`.

The full working example is available here:
https://github.com/akollegger/neo4j-trials/blob/master/src/test/java/org/akollegger/neo4j/trials/richardw/ExecutionResultIteratorTrial.java

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Andreas

Comment: I've added some basic explanation in the javadoc as well, viewable at http://api.neo4j.org

Comment: It's important to note that this is a `scala.collection.Iterator` and NOT a `java.util.Iterator` !!!

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Map<String,Object> row : result) {
   Node x = (Node)row.get("x");
   for (String prop : x.getPropertyKeys()) {
      System.out.println(prop +": "+x.getProperty(prop));
   }
}
```

Comment: It works when x has single value in each row. If x has multiple values in a single row, how will you iterate? (For ex). under x,  mango, orange, banana in the first row. pear, cherry in the second row.  when I work with such exampe, it throws me classcast exception. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

```
Iterator<Object> columnAs = result.columnAs("n");
while(columnAs.hasNext())
{
Node n = (Node)columnAs.next();
for (String key : n.getPropertyKeys()) {
sysout("{ " + key + " : " + n.getProperty(key)+ " } ");
}
```

This might help you out

Answer (score 1):

In newer versions of the java driver one can traverse like this.

```
Driver driver = GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://localhost:7687", AuthTokens.basic("neo4j", "neo4j"));
Session session = driver.session();
List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();

StatementResult cursor = session.run("match (l:League)<-[]-(t:Team) return t.short_name");
while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    teams.add(cursor.next().get(cursor.keys().get(0)).toString());
}

session.close();
driver.close();
```